# EKRecurrenceRule how to describe exclusion?

Tags: ios6, ekevent, ekeventkit

I have a rule "9-10am very Monday morning from Sept 08 2013 to Oct 30, 2013 except Oct 14, 2013)". How could I code it into EKRecurrenceRule? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. After some researches, my conclusion is, one could not do that. Hope iOS7 is better.

Comment: Hello, i'm trying to create a recurring event but escape some occurrences, did you find any approche to escape dates ? any help is much appreciated.